# is it possible to put a interactive graph chart in google doc?

Tags: php, graph, google-drive-api, interactive

I have a PHP code that creates google doc from html as string.

```
$subcontent = "<h1>Some Text</h1>";
$mkFile = $this->_service->files->insert($file, array('data' => $subcontent, 'mimeType' => 'text/html', 'convert' => true));
```

is it possible that in the created google doc can automatically insert a interactive graph giving manually input value inside the google doc content?

Answer (score 0):

not possible in google docs as of nov. 2015